# Move block in Excel to line N

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Trying to write code to move the block at the N line in Excel, but alas so far nothing. Suggests that this is how you can:

```
namespace MoveBlockExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application objExcel = new Application();
            objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;

            objExcel.Range range = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("B10:F15");
            range.Paste(ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("B1:F5")); 

            Workbook objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Template_Modified.xls");
            Worksheet objWorkSheet = objWorkBook.Sheets[3];
        }
    }
}
```

But the code is not compiled, based on what objExcel not found.

Comment: `ObjExcel.Range R` is the nonsense part. Should be `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range R`. Then it will properly fail on `ObjWorkSheet` with `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Method "Paste" is not found

Comment: @Arsen have you added references to the Excel.Interop and the using statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cut the range `B10:F15` and paste it to `B1:F5`.

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Template_Modified.xls");
Worksheet worksheet = app.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Range["B10:F15"].Cut(worksheet.Range["B1:F5"]);
```

Make sure that your refences include Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel:
[image]

Comment: Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[3]; (solved)
if(Sheets == 2)
{
workbook.Sheets[3]
}
How to fix? Why do I need to add +1 to the array?

Comment: Please start another question if it is not related to the main question. And if the answer helped please accept it. Workbook.Sheets accepts either index or worksheet name, maybe it is selecting by name? Is your worksheet name 3?